# iOS wifi disconnects on certain networks (e.g. eduroam) when switching to another app

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi

Hi all—I'm not sure if others have seen this, but I've been noticing for the last few months that my iPhone (SE 2, currently iOS 16.4.1 [a]), once it establishes a connection with certain networks (like eduroam), *constantly* disconnects only if I switch to another app (e.g. from Settings to Safari, or Instagram, etc.). If I keep it in the same app, it stays connected for around 30 seconds to a minute, and then sometimes disconnects/sometimes doesn't.

Again, this only happens with certain busy networks, like eduroam; smaller networks, like my home wifi, it stays reliably connected (generally). I only started really noticing this in the last 3-4 months—before that, it would simply stay connected.

I have done a network reset on the phone, 2 months back, and the problem remained. I'm loath to do a complete reset of the phone (mainly to save various app/bank activation settings, etc.), unless this is the only option. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with [Eduroam](https://eduroam.org/where/). Have you contacted [Eduroam Support](https://eduroam.org/support/)?

Comment: I was reading up on Eduroam and it appears to be a “network sharing agreement” among institutions.  As long as you are a valid member of one institution, you can access the network of any other institution.  This requires RADIUS authentication. If the authentication fails due to latency (no response in allotted time), it will not connect.  That’s just my theory, but I believe this to be the case.